# modify css bubble

Tags: html, css, dom

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 10px;
    font-size:8px;
}
.container:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #CAD5E0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a class="container">1</a>​
```

​Can someone explain to me how this css should be modified in order to place the pointer (triangle) to the left side of the box.

I have it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTZwA/

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Look at the left position and the border color lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update these two lines:

```css
.container:before {
    right: 100%;
    border-color: transparent #CAD5E0 transparent transparent;
    /* All other properties are identical */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YnD6C/

Comment: Would be nice to explain why, i have appended an answer to compliment yours.

Comment: If the OP would have at least shown [what he's tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), I'd go into explanation mode. Since he hasn't, I don't know what he does or doesn't know...

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin that will make bubbles for you :)

When you make arrows you have to think in opposites.

Add the color value to the OPPOSITE side of the one you want it to be.

Want it to go left? Put the color on right.

http://www.rosefalk.dk/library/base/index.html